# Linear Gradient React Native pattern

Tags: reactjs, native, gradient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otqen.png)

Does anyone know why this gradient line appears to have a line pattern and how to clean it up?

<LinearGradient
colors={['#384275','#050C30']}>

Comment: The issue is that the gradient is wayyyyy stretched out. The top of your image matches your lighter color ("#384275") but the bottom of your image isn't even close to your darker color. It's just a few shades darker than the top, which is causing the banding (there just aren't enough colors in between to make it smooth). What are you applying that gradient to? Is it something very large that is mostly off screen? Or do you need to specify a screen range along with your color range?

Comment: Also, a little more information about what you tried, what the rest of this screen looked like, etc with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would probably get you some better answers.